# Runtime Permissions for Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, runtime-permissions

I know that android 6.0 requires runtime permissions. Could you please help me implement runtime permissions for Bluetooth? I tried using the example on https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html but was getting a bunch of errors. Thanks.

Comment: have you added these premissions androidManifest.xml
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />`

Comment: also add permission 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  />`

also 

`WifiManager.getScanResults();

BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND;

BluetoothLeScanner.startScan();`

Comment: @EmdadHossain  Hi, I am getting an error for BluetoothLescanner.startScan(), cannot be resolved

Comment: can you show me the error?

Comment: @EmdadHossain  My code: in the onCreate method I have:            BluetoothDevice = ACTION_FOUND;
WifiManager.getScanResults();
BluetoothLeScanner.startScan();    It says I am missing permissions for each one and it says cannot make static referene even though I have all the permissions you said in my manifest file

Comment: what is this line? BluetoothDevice = ACTION_FOUND; 
are you saying BluetoothDevice .ACTION_FOUND; ? may be that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a **Permit** object to start requesting permission(s) from user.
Firstly initialize the Permit object passing your activity

```
Permit permit=new Permit(MainActivity.this);
```

Then attach a listner to this object

```
permit.setOnPermitStatusListner(new Permit.OnPermitStatusListner()
{
@Override
public void onAllPermitsGranded()
{
  // ALL PERMITS ACCEPTED
}

@Override
public void onSomePermitsDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermits)
{
  // SOME PERMITS ACCEPTED
}

@Override
public void onAllPermitsDenied()
{
  // ALL PERMITS DENIED
}
});
```

Then ask for what all permissions you need to work(Must be declared in the Manifest)

```
permit.askPermitsFor(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,Manifest.permission.<Other BT permissions>);
```

You need to **add this library** to work with Permit object. Here is the complete documentation : https://github.com/sangeethnandakumar/TestTube